# Words for the two "directions" of the meanings words gain or lose over time

Tags: etymology, semantic-shift, paired-word-requests

Maybe this belongs on "Linguistics" but since it's about an English word, I suppose they'd only send me here.

Over time, some words gather more and more meanings to themselves. Ironically, these words are often small like, "by".

Other words seem to shed meanings, or rather, they devolve meanings to new words. In the New Testament, Jesus tells people to "arise" from their bed, elsewhere "the resurrection" appears. But this is actually just the noun form, i.e. "the arising." Now, no one except by poetic license would refer to their "resurrection" from bed; it has become a specialized form of "standing up" (from death.)

Is there a pair of words to describe on the one hand the accreation and on the other the fragmentation of words and their meanings?

Comment: These are **Metaphors**. Take a look at Lakoff and Johnson's _Metaphors We Live By_. That goes into the process. There's a large literature (several literatures, in fact) about the use of metaphors in Biblical interpretation.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow you. What are metaphors?

Comment: Are you asking about situations where one of several meanings of a word becomes so predominant that to use the word in one of its other meanings sounds far too strange, or at the very least a sort of play on words?  Note that the *verb* **resurrect** still can be used in non-religious contexts without the "spillover" that accompanies use of the noun.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a single-word term for a major change in a word's meaning?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/370488/is-there-a-single-word-term-for-a-major-change-in-a-words-meaning)

Comment: Sort of, but I was interested in not the general term for the change but whether there were particular words for the direction of the shift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Widening**/**generalization** and **narrowing**/**specialization** of meaning appear to be the usual terms, for situations where the range extends (e.g. the verb *tape* or *video* going making a recording on magnetic tape to making recordings in other ways) or contracts (*corn* went from grains in general to *maize*). The Wikipedia article [Semantic shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change) covers various types of changes of meaning of words, and sets out various typologies including those of Arsène Darmesteter, Leonard Bloomfield, Stephen Ullman, who all used *widening* and *narrowing*. Andreas Blank used *generalization* and *specialization*, which will get you more points at Scrabble.

Comment: Corn becoming just maize is a better example than mine.

Comment: @KTM: (Or maize becoming corn... ;-))

Comment: @Drew: I have no idea how to articulate the question, but I wonder how to tell which formulation is more descriptive.

Comment: This is just for your curiousity, but it seems to me that the corn/grain distinction really took off [after the repeal of the Corn Laws](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=corn%2Cgrain%2Ccorn%3Aeng_gb_2019%2Cgrain%3Aeng_gb_2019%2Cpotato&year_start=1800&year_end=1900&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=0). "potato" is there to mark the concurrent famine.

Comment: @KTM: My comment wasn't a critique or disagreement. It involves the difference (for both your formulation and mine) of *use* and *mention*. For *mention* we have quotation marks. ;-)